# ERROR occur with write_once using python in raspberry PI

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

```
import os
import select
write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')
# Pin to work with
pin_base = '/sys/class/gpio/gpio22/'
def write_once(path, value):
   with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(value)
      f = open(os.path.join(pin_base, 'value'), 'r')
      write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'direction'),
       'in')
      write_once(os.path.join(pin_base, 'edge'),
       'falling')
      po = select.poll()
      po.register(f, select.POLLPRI)
while 1:
    events = po.poll(100)
    if not events:
       print ('timeout')
    else:
       f.seek(0)
       state_last = f.read()
       print 'Val: %s' % state_last
```

The error i received from the system:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/trigger.py", line 5, in <module>
    write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')
NameError: name 'write_once' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the function `write_once` *before* declaring it. You must move the following line to the end of your script:

```
write_once(os.path.join('/sys/class/gpio', 'export'), '22')
```

Comment: If i put that line to the end of my script then it received error.

Comment: This is the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/trigger.py", line 15, in <module>
    f = open(os.path.join(pin_base, 'value'), 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/gpio/gpio22/value'

Comment: This is a completely different error. If this answer solved your _original_ problem, mark it as "answered" and post the new error as another question to attract more answers.

Comment: Do you still get the error `NameError: name 'write_once' is not defined`?